# JavaScript settimeout method call to a jsp page is maintaining the session alive for a user

Tags: java, jsp

When I'm making a call to a JSP page to get a value from server in span of 5 seconds interval then the existing session for a logged-in user is not getting expired due to this setTimeout call from js to jsp page.

Is there any way that i can make a call for js to jsp without disturbing the created session for a user. i.e. if i am logged in and kept the webpage idle for 15 mins it should expire irrespective of setTimeout !

---

**Sample code for jsp hit.**

```
    function refreshBranchStatus(message) {
        var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
        client.open("GET", "status.jsp", false);
        client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
        client.send(message);
        return client.responseText;
        window.setTimeout("refreshBranchStatus(null)", 5000);
    }
```

---

**status.jsp file**

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
<%@ page import="com.sample.Obj"%>
<%
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", -1);
    response.setContentType("text/plain");  
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(Obj.getInstance().status);  
 %>
```

Thank you

Comment: Not sure I fully understand you, but it sounds to me as if you want client side JavaScript to be able to invalidate a server side session, but then again you write "without disturbing the created session". Not sure I'm the only one who doesn't understand it but can you maybe clarify.

Comment: simple if i logged-in at my website, later I have a requirement to change a status dynamically without user input. to achieve this i'm using setTimeout in js and calling a jsp code to get a value from server and update it on webpage but this making the user session to be alive even after 2~3hrs and its not expiring though there's no user activity on the page..

Comment: So you want to invalidate your session on inactivity irrespective of the request that is sent to the webapp? That means you want to ignore this particilar `GET` request while extending session?

Comment: Yes exactly i'm looking for...